# When Chaitra Navratri mahurat 2017 is starting - 28th or 29th

Tags: navrathri

Chaitra Shukla Pratipada has began onTuesday, March 28 at 8.26 am. Chaitra Amavasya is ended on 8.27 am in the morning of March 28 this year and Chaitra Shukla Pratipra has started  from 8.28 minutes and the sunrise standard will end on March 29 at 6.44 minutes. Many Pandit ji has different opinion about it and some are saying that as Chaitra Shukla Pratipra has started  from 8.28 minutes, so Chaitra Navratri mahurat is from 8.28 minutes on 28th march and it is until 29th march morning.

Our pundit ji said that it has started on 28th from 8.28 minutes.

according to different websites, there are different opinions given such as Wikipedia has mentioned that it is starting on 29th march.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_New_Year%27s_days

Anyone has any other opinion on it?

Comment: You can check from drikpanchang.com..

Comment: Yes, I had already checked this website and start date was 28th. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hari Om! This is the post made by well know astrologer-researcher Narasimha Rao. I hope it will be useful :) 
"There is a little confusion in India on whether the new year starts on 2017 March 28 or 29. If you live in US or Europe, there is no confusion - Chaitra Sukla Pratipada started on Monday night and ends on Tuesday night. So it is clearly Tuesday.
In India, Chaitra Sukla Pratipada starts on Monday *after* sunrise and ends *before* the sunrise on Tuesday. Again, as per shastras, it is on Tuesday.

---

However, some people do not use Drik siddhanta and erroneously stick to outdated formulas for computing planets. They get the end of Pratipada a little after sunrise on Wednesday.
Ancients did curve fitting on observations of their time and gave simple formulas for easy computation without constant observation. These formulas were meant to be refined from era to era, to match observations within some precision. However, some scholars of Kali yuga decided to just use them without refinement for ever, thus considerably deviating from observations!
Even in that case, Pratipada does not last long enough after sunrise on Wednesday. So, as per the minimum time given by shastras, Wednesday does not qualify and it is still Tuesday. But they ignore the minimum time dictum and claim that Wednesday is the new year day.
They are using wrong planetary calculations and also ignoring the minimum time dictum. Unfortunately, two wrongs don't make a right in this case. :-)

---

In any case, I do think this new year definition based on Chaitra Sukla Pratipada is a relatively modern definition. Upanishads speak of a different lunar new year. Even today, there are many different new lunar years defined in different parts of the world. People take new Moon and full Moon of various months as the start of lunar new year."
Happy Yugadi, Ugadi, Samvatsaradi, Gudi Padwa or lunar new year, to those who celebrate it today/tomorrow).:)

Comment: You should cite sources.